# Как извлечь нужные значения из ассоциативных массивов и записать их в индексированный массив без ключа?

Tags: php

В массиве приходят несколько массивов, с одинаковыми ключами, вида:

```
Array(

[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => parent3
        [text] => parent_test1
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => parent4
        [text] => parent_test2
    )
) //и так далее
```

Необходимо взять значение ключа `'name'` из всех массивов и записать их в индексированный массив без ключа, что бы получилось так:

```
$array = array("parent3", "parent4");
```

Через `foreach` записывается только одно значение. Как это лучше всего сделать?

Comment: Откуда берутся эти массивы?

Comment: @Ипатьев из базы данных, такой вид формирует библиотека

Comment: Тогда надо сразу такой массив из БД и запрашивать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если отвечать на вопрос буквально, то в РНР есть функция `array_column()`:

```
$data = array_column($source, 'name');
```

Но в общем случае данные из БД следует сразу получать в нужном виде:

```
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT name from t")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Comment: `array_column` только с php > 5.5.0, у хостера часто стоит 5.3 по умолчанию

Comment: если у хостера строит версия из прошлого десятилетия, уже много лет не поддерживаемая, то следует задуматься о его адекватности. Хотя конечно для школьников, экономящих 50 рублей на обедах чтобы оплатить убогий хостинг, предупреждение актуально.

Comment: все виртуальные хостинги, которые видел - были на 5.3.1, чтобы переключиться на версию выше - нужно было включать php_как_cgi. но это оффтоп, я не хочу сказать что решение плохое, просто подсказать ТС почему у него может вдруг не заработать когда зальёт скрипт на хостинг.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ с `pdo` и `array_column` более актуален, но если вдруг надо именно через `foreach`

```
$res = array();
foreach($arr as $value){
    $res[] = $value['name'];
}
```